# what am I doing wrong with my full width video cover?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a full width video cover for the header of a web but it keep bugging, What am I doing wrong?

this is part of my code:

```
<section id="home">
        <video poster="assets/img/home-bg.png" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" id="bgvid">
            <source src="assets/video/garage-video.mp4"" type="video/mp4"/>
         <!--  <source src="assets/video/trailer.webm" type="video/webm"/> --> 
        </video>

        <!-- HEADER LOGO & NAV -->
        <div class="filtro">

            <div class="logo">
            <img src="assets/img/garage-logo-blanco.png" alt="logo garage">
        </div>
```

This is the css:

```
section#home video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: 1;
}

.filtro {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(40, 88, 162, .55);
}
```

here is the entire code:

https://github.com/Luisbtz/garage3.0

here is the demo where you can find the bug, (The extra right padding):

http://luisbenitez.xyz/garage3.0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is not in the `video` but in other part of your HTML, here:

```css
section#confiables .mecanico-img .left {
  left: 20vh;
  position: relative;
  top: 30vh;
}
```

remove `left:20vh`

Comment: I knew that was something I did after! Thak you so much! that was very dumb!